# Laravel authentication or mix of Laravel and vuejs authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication, web, vue.js

I've a question about simplicity of a task. I'm fairly new to laravel and vue js, I'm used to php and javascript though.

I hope my question makes sense since I'm not sure if the technologies work as I think.

So I want to do a SPA project with laravel as backend, vuejs as frontend and mysql for the database. I need the site to be online and want an authentication to grant user access to different parts of the website. Let's say, you have to register yourself. If it's a normal user, he can see the "UserDashboard" and if it is an admin he can see the "AdminDashboard".

I've came across a couple of tutorials which show how to create an authentication system by using vue components to handle login/register/logout... It's pretty complicated and messy in my opinion.

Is it easier to just use laravel authentication and blade templates for authentication and then show the SPA for registered users/admins? If that's possible. Only saw the first option I mention for the moment.

Edit :

Here is a picture to illustrate last approach

[Laravel authentication, then show SPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXgcV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Laravel Mix, simply have one blade template that hosts your application (it's already set in Laravel). However, if you're using Laravel for API and a separate project for the front-end SPA, use Passport. [Here's one of the ways](http://ykamal.com/how-to-consume-laravel-passport-jwt-tokens-with-javascript/) to do it.

If you are using Laravel Mix, the CSRF token is already in a meta tag and is being added to Axios. All you need to do is make on blade template show your app.

You can also have separate blade views for login / registration etc and show SPA when logged in. But that's not really the best practice. Since I've figured out how to use Passport, I've always gone the separate vue project route.

Comment: I've heard that using passeport is a bit difficult and more oriented towards bigger projects. My project will only have 2 to 3 users. What do you think about it?

I've also made a test with JWT tokens and only using the blade to show SPA. So that's what you define as Laravel mix I guess.

I've found the last approach you mention to be the easiest and more clear one to me. I've made a test by using laravel authentication and show SPA when logged in. I like the fact that the authentiction is separate since I only need it to show the SPA. I'll show an img in edit part.

Comment: You're almost there. Once logged in, in that view you are loading, have the element with the ID you want for you app, and make sure the JS files needed for the SPA are loading in that page. They will initiate the SPA in that view. You can also have a `section` named `scripts` for the blade view and use `@yield('scripts')` and dynamically add your js files for the view there.